# Kernel reports wlan0 "connection lost" frequently

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel

I'm getting this message frequently:

```
wlan0: Connection to AP f8:d1:11:44:01:06 lost
```

This happens only on my work, not my house.

I workaround this with `sudo service network-manager restart` or rebooting.

Below follow some additional informations.

```
======== Wireless-Info START ========

System-Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

tux 3.16.0-33-generic x86_64,  Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, trusty

CPU    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 450  @ 2.40GHz
Memory : 3751 MB
Uptime : 18:09:12 up  9:35,  2 users,  load average: 0,33, 0,62, 0,55


lspci ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8172] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8172]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se
--
06:00.5 Ethernet controller [0200]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [197b:0250] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:4120]
    Kernel driver in use: jme


lsusb ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 22b8:2e84 Motorola PCS 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 15d9:0a4c Trust International B.V. USB+PS/2 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


PCMCIA Card Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



iwconfig ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"AP-1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC C-01 AP-1>   
          Bit Rate=18 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:78   Missed beacon:0



rfkill ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      Interface        Soft blocked  Hard blocked
0: phy0: Wireless LAN      no            no


lsmod ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

rtl8192se              63162  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8192se
rtlwifi                64255  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192se
mac80211              652718  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192se
cfg80211              494362  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
wmi                    19193  0 


module parameters ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

cfg80211      (2): cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=N | ieee80211_regdom=00
mac80211      (5): beacon_loss_count=7 | ieee80211_default_rc_algo=minstrel_ht | max_nullfunc_tries=2 | max_probe_tries=5 | probe_wait_ms=500
rtl8192se     (5): debug=0 | fwlps=N | ips=Y | swenc=N | swlps=Y
wmi           (2): debug_dump_wdg=N | debug_event=N


nm-tool ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

State: connected (global)
======================o=============o===========o=============o=========o===========o==============o===========
 Interface & ID       | Type        | Driver    | State       | Default | Speed     | Support      | HW Addr   
======================o=============o===========o=============o=========o===========o==============o===========
 eth0                 | Wired       | jme       | unavailable | no      |           |              | <MAC eth0>
----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------
 wlan0  [AP-1] | 802.11 WiFi | rtl8192se | connected   | yes     | 18 Mb/s   | WEP/WPA/WPA2 | <MAC wlan0>

    *AP-1:    Infra, <MAC C-01 AP-1>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 72 WEP
    Wi-Fi Pop Som:   Infra, <MAC C-NA AP-2>, Freq 2472 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA WPA2

    Address:         192.168.1.199
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1
    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             8.8.4.4
----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------


NetworkManager.state ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true


NetworkManager.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false


NM WiFi Profiles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

AP-1          : ssid=AP-1 | permissions=user:myuser:; | mac-address=<MAC wlan0> | ipv4=manual | ipv6=ignore 
AP-3 : ssid=AP-3 | mac-address=<MAC wlan0> | ipv4=auto | ipv6=ignore 


interfaces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

resolv.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

nameserver 192.168.1.240
nameserver 201.10.120.2    # Brasil Telecom-3 BR  
nameserver 201.10.120.3    # Brasil Telecom-4 BR
nameserver 127.0.1.1       # SYS-127.0.1.1
nameserver 201.10.1.2      # Brasil Telecom-5 BR  
nameserver 201.10.120.2    # SYS-201.10.120.2
nameserver 189.38.95.96    # SYS-189.38.95.96
nameserver 127.0.1.1


Routes & Ping ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Tabela de Roteamento IP do Kernel
Destino         Roteador        MáscaraGen.    Opções Métrica Ref   Uso Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.677/4.633/8.589/3.956 ms

--- 192.168.1.240 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.763/1.319/1.876/0.557 ms

--- 201.10.120.2    # Brasil Telecom-3 BR ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1009ms


--- 201.10.120.3    # Brasil Telecom-4 BR ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms


--- 127.0.1.1       # SYS-127.0.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.062/0.062/0.063/0.007 ms

--- 201.10.1.2      # Brasil Telecom-5 BR ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1006ms


--- 201.10.120.2    # SYS-201.10.120.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1008ms


--- 189.38.95.96    # SYS-189.38.95.96 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.989/16.627/17.265/0.638 ms

--- 127.0.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.062/0.064/0.067/0.008 ms


iw reg get ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

(Region : pt_BR.UTF-8)
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS


iwlist chan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 (2.412 GHz) - 13 (2.472 GHz)

          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)


iwlist scan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC C-01 AP-1>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=18 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AP-1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000109e5df7311
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago


blacklist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci


modinfo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[rtl8192se]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192sefw.bin
srcversion:     FF2890C4D22E859C393BF83
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
srcversion:     3273ECD6028617EFD27E4F4
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
srcversion:     8362106E96F806A9DBAE565
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
srcversion:     5410C94462FA26A0A3F256C
depends:        cfg80211
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
srcversion:     4A525D9D32B0C6D120CA547
depends:        
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/wmi.ko
srcversion:     347CF30B94B5549A75865A8
depends:        
parm:           debug_event:Log WMI Events [0/1] (bool)
parm:           debug_dump_wdg:Dump available WMI interfaces [0/1] (bool)


udev rules ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# PCI device 0x197b:0x0250 (jme)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8172 (rtl8192se)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC wlan0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"


Custom files/entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/etc/modules        : Default
/etc/rc.local       : Default
/etc/modprobe.d     : Not Default
/etc/pm/(cnf|pw|sl) : Default

[/etc/modprobe.d]
iwlwifi.conf      : remove iwlwifi \
                    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
                    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
mlx4.conf         : softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
modesetting.conf  : options cirrus modeset=1
                    options mgag200 modeset=1
qemu-system-x86.conf: options kvm_intel nested=1


Kernel boot line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-33-generic root=/dev/mapper/fast--vg-root--lv ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7


dmesg ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[    0.030473] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.030500] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
[    1.447550] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    1.448392] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    4.116447] jme: JMicron JMC2XX ethernet driver version 1.0.8
[    4.117852] jme 0000:06:00.5 eth0: JMC250 Gigabit Ethernet chiprev:23 pcirev:3 macaddr:<MAC eth0>
[    8.009506] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    8.146877] rtl8192se: FW Power Save off (module option)
[    8.146947] rtl8192se: Driver for Realtek RTL8192SE/RTL8191SE
[    8.146947] Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192sefw.bin
[    8.164035] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   12.796163] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.148317] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   27.347139] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[   27.357209] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[   27.364939] wlan0: authenticated
[   27.365146] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   27.368214] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[   27.370695] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=16)
[   27.372871] wlan0: associated
[   27.372899] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  105.344339] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  106.457194] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  106.476733] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  106.580482] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[  106.584412] wlan0: authenticated
[  106.584658] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  106.588445] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  106.692496] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[  106.694915] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=16)
[  106.697102] wlan0: associated
[  111.633101] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  112.745853] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  112.765374] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  112.766951] wlan0: authenticated
[  112.767133] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  112.769162] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  112.771944] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=16)
[  112.773656] wlan0: associated
[  119.926076] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  121.042899] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  121.062338] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  121.063923] wlan0: authenticated
[  121.064146] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  121.066160] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  121.068762] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=16)
[  121.070436] wlan0: associated
[  545.223508] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  546.368964] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  546.388469] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  546.390380] wlan0: authenticated
[  546.390603] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  546.392260] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  546.398315] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[  546.399996] wlan0: associated
[  553.552659] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  554.665844] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  554.685388] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  554.688624] wlan0: authenticated
[  554.688792] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  554.689328] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  554.695346] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[  554.697038] wlan0: associated
[  561.849748] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  562.962953] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  562.982514] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  562.987724] wlan0: authenticated
[  562.987876] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  562.990434] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  563.094494] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[  563.198571] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 3/3)
[  563.302621] wlan0: association with <MAC C-01 AP-1> timed out
[  564.655893] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  564.675600] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  564.677023] wlan0: authenticated
[  564.677213] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  564.679500] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  564.783545] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[  564.789308] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[  564.791483] wlan0: associated
[  572.152097] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  573.277238] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  573.296882] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  573.400866] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[  573.504926] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 3/3)
[  573.507904] wlan0: authenticated
[  573.508114] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  573.508928] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  573.515450] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[  573.517622] wlan0: associated
[  596.495146] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  597.612222] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  597.631884] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  597.735846] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[  597.739044] wlan0: authenticated
[  597.739207] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  597.739884] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  597.746111] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[  597.748325] wlan0: associated
[  604.796316] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  605.909602] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  605.929049] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  605.938124] wlan0: authenticated
[  605.938334] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  605.940928] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  606.045066] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[  606.149098] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 3/3)
[  606.152496] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[  606.154720] wlan0: associated
[  615.098670] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  616.212000] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  616.231530] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  616.235073] wlan0: authenticated
[  616.235268] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  616.239320] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  616.243285] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[  616.244935] wlan0: associated
[  625.400999] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[  626.374126] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[  626.393699] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  626.497681] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[  626.505357] wlan0: authenticated
[  626.505782] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  626.509673] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[  626.519668] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[  626.521824] wlan0: associated
[ 1960.895095] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 1962.005569] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 1962.024944] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 1962.029181] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1962.029399] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1962.032730] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 1962.036736] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 1962.038376] wlan0: associated
[ 1993.252011] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 1994.369355] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 1994.388961] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 1994.492824] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[ 1994.494333] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1994.494575] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 1994.496789] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 1994.499278] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 1994.501455] wlan0: associated
[ 2007.571943] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 2008.682003] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 2008.701660] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 2008.703122] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2008.703367] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 2008.705546] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 2008.708066] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 2008.709760] wlan0: associated
[ 7085.170491] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 7086.283858] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 7086.303256] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7086.306845] wlan0: authenticated
[ 7086.307122] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 7086.311085] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7086.313478] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 7086.315189] wlan0: associated
[ 7372.198389] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 7373.308612] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 7373.328195] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7373.432099] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[ 7373.434226] wlan0: authenticated
[ 7373.434471] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 7373.436065] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7373.440904] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 7373.443084] wlan0: associated
[ 7380.492433] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 7381.605770] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 7381.625291] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7381.629225] wlan0: authenticated
[ 7381.629418] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 7381.633092] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7381.635628] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 7381.637324] wlan0: associated
[ 7388.789589] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 7389.902849] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 7389.922390] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7389.928358] wlan0: authenticated
[ 7389.928583] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 7389.930205] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7389.933643] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 7389.935324] wlan0: associated
[ 7407.112826] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 7408.234249] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 7408.253600] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7408.255175] wlan0: authenticated
[ 7408.255379] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 7408.257461] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7408.260001] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 7408.261694] wlan0: associated
[ 7415.410031] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[ 7416.523728] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[ 7416.542717] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7416.544166] wlan0: authenticated
[ 7416.544356] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 7416.546581] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[ 7416.549061] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=12)
[ 7416.550743] wlan0: associated
[15450.737536] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[15451.847821] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[15451.867330] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[15451.868859] wlan0: authenticated
[15451.869099] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[15451.871117] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[15451.873583] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=8)
[15451.875260] wlan0: associated
[32579.851880] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC C-01 AP-1> lost
[32580.965382] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 AP-1>
[32580.984676] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[32581.088608] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[32581.192588] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 3/3)
[32581.226122] wlan0: authenticated
[32581.226383] rtl8192se 0000:05:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[32581.228694] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 1/3)
[32581.332754] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 AP-1> (try 2/3)
[32581.347362] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 AP-1> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=6)
[32581.349529] wlan0: associated

    ======== Done ========
```

Comment: What the hell – `WEP/TKIP`!?? Is this a call from mid-00's who want their WiFi vulnerabilities back? Please tell your employer, that their wireless network encryption can be cracked practically within minutes since a decade ago.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Wasn't I that configured this network. But thank you to suggest this. I'll take note. :D